# How do I make the goopy liquid outside the pipette/ dropper?

Tags: sculpting

I want to make the liquid to look goopy and get it outside the dropper (most tutorials I see are for liquids inside the glass). I dont intend to animate it.

This is the dropper I've made so far
[image]

for practice (i'm still figuring out Blender). My reference image is
[image]
(this might actually be a photo).

Any more suggestions to make it realistic/ better are welcomed!

(I also am not sure about the tags for this post. Is this sculpting?)

Comment: I see 2 options here.  the first, and probably simpler option, would be to make a cylinder around the dropper, sculpt it to look more like liquid dropping down, and then give it a liquid-like material.  The 2nd option, which I'm not entirely sure how it would turn out, but if you wanted to try to make it extra realistic, you could make an actual liquid simulation with a cylinder on the outside as your domain, and then tweak the settings until you get the desired dripping result

Comment: @ETHANDAY Thank you! I'm going to try the first option as it feels more familiar. if I can manage to get something there, I'll also the try the second one to go beyond my reference image. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem.  Happy to help :D